# Draw vertical line in scatter plot?

Tags: excel, libreoffice

I'm using Libreoffice (but I think that this is similar in Excel) and I need to draw a vertical line in correspondence of the green points in this image:

[image]

Possibly follow the line style that I used in the legend. How can I do this?

Comment: This question is off topic. You need to post this on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: @alex.pulver why?

Comment: Stackoverflow is a community for programmers. Your question is about how to use LibreOffice/MS Excel. Super User is the community for software users. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel you can use vertical error bars. If you want to have a line drop vertically to the axis, use  the settings with Minus and 100%

[image]

Comment: Thanks, what I was looking for, but now one vertical appears for every point. How can insert *only one bar*?

Comment: Delete the error bars for the data points that you don't want to see them for. Or, create a helper series with just ONE data point and add the error bars to that series. Some advanced charting effects require a bit more setup work.